# Entity Framework creates mad bin tables? Why?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4

Have just started out with EF for Oracle in targeting .Net 4.0.

Have added a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project and imported 7 tables that are not complicated. ALL OF THESE HAVE PRIMARY KEYS.

When I look at the model diagram I have a warning message:

> Error 6002: The table/view
>   'SDRMAN.BIN$p2oWaPic9h7gQAkKPRBwJQ==$0'
>   does not have a primary key defined.
>   The key has been inferred and the
>   definition was created as a read-only
>   table/view.

I can't figure it out - an it just looks CRAZY!

[image]

All these BIN tables.  Obviously something has gone wrong here - can anyone guess as to what is going wrong here?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These "tables" are actually old dropped tables.

By default Oracle does not really drop a table when you run `DROP TABLE` but moves it to the "recycle bin".

You can either disable the recycle bin or simply purge it to get rid of the old ones:

To permanently delete thos tables use:

```
purge recyclebin;
```

You can disable the usage of the recycle bin for your session using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF;
```

More details are available in the manual:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01511

Comment: Well, that really worked.  I had no idea about this recycle bin!  Many thanks.